# How can I ask when my internship ends?

Tags: internship, termination

This is my second time interning at this company; last year I interned throughout the summer, and my internship was then extended until January. I accepted an internship offer with the company again this summer.

When I initially spoke to the recruiter about the offer, he mentioned continuing the internship during the fall semester, since I am only working 2 days per week during the summer. There was no definite plan, and I never even spoke to my manager about such an arrangement.

According to my WorkDay profile, my end date is August 25. However, my manager continues to assign additional work that will take far more time to complete; I am 99% sure he's aware I cannot implement several software features in 5 days. To me it seems like an uncomfortale situation, but:

**how do I ask when my internship ends?**

Comment: You don't have an internship contract stating how much you should be paid and how long your internship lasts ?

Comment: Don't assume your manager and HR know the same things. Very likely they never talked to each other about your end date. Are you planning to leave on August 25 like WorkDay says, or do you want to stay longer? It's your job to make sure they are on the same page about your career.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Boss, you're assigning a lot of work, but according to WorkDay, my end date is August 25th. Can we have a talk about when my internship ends, and what I should focus on before then?

You probably shouldn't overthink this. It's generally perfectly fine to just ask things.

Answer (score 3):

Go and talk to you manager and, depending on whether you want to stay longer or not either say something like

> Hi [Manager], Just wondering if you were aware that my Internship is listed as ending on August 25th and I don't think that leaves enough time for me to finish X, Y and Z that you assigned. I'm happy to continue past that date as I should be able to fit it around school if you are?

or

> Hi [Manager], Just wondering if you were aware that my Internship is listed as ending on August 25th and I don't think that leaves enough time for me to finish X, Y and Z that you assigned. As I won't be here after that date is there anyone you want me to hand X, Y and Z over to?